# Load failed: Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0*3c. Line 610, position 3

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

[image: Load failed]

Not able to open solution, I'n not getting how to resolve it any help appreciated,
Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found whats causing this error,
Xamarin.ios.commontargets file has that "<" at line 610,
I removed it it's working fine now.
Thank you

Comment: I had a xml file with merge confilcts which caused the same error

Answer (score 1):

I had the error on line 2, position 2 when attempting to load an Android project.

But the error was in `AndroidManifest.xml` - some merge comments.